# Calling $("#form").submit(... doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something upon submission of my form. However, no matter what I do, nothing happens when I submit.

This is what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for @sale, url: sale_path(@sale), id:"sale-form", method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= text_field_tag "code", "", id:"code"%>
    <%= f.submit "Find", class:"ps-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sale-form").on("submit", function(){
        $("html").hide();
    });
</script>
```

and this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sale-form").submit(function(){
        $("html").hide();
    });
</script>
```

I read that if anything is named `submit`, that can interfere with the jQuery `submit` action. However, nothing on my page is named that.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "This is what my form looks like" — Please provide the HTML and not whatever server side code you are using to generate the HTML.

Comment: Replace `$("#sale-form").on(etc)` with `alert( $("#sale-form").length )`. What does it say?

Comment: I think you have to hide html element like div or something because you can not hide html tag

Comment: Add your code inside doc.ready `$(function() { $("#sale-form").on("submit... });` - it's not possible to tell from what you've provided, but if your script runs before the form, it won't find it (hence the .length check request above)

Comment: *"nothing happens when I submit"* - add a breakpoint / alert / console.log inside the submit event to see if the event is firing at least (which doesn't count as nothing happening!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a very embarrassing mistake...I should have known this, but when it comes to Rails forms, adding `id:"something"` into the `form_for` line doesn't actually do anything. To manipulate the html of the form, I have to do `html:{id:"something"}`.

So in my case, the solution is to do this:

```
<%= form_for @sale, url: sale_path(@sale), html:{id:"sale-form"}, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have a high reputation to comment.*
Can you check the form submit button type. Most likely you have set it as `button` instead of `submit`

Comment: Exactly, we have no idea what `<%= f.submit` *actually* generates - hence the very first comment form @Quentin (not to belittle this "comment")